# WPF Can anyone explain DataGrid.items.add(object)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to WPF and confused about this point.

DataGrid.items.add("text") adds an empty row in datagrid.
Everyone suggest to bind the source to INumerable collection.

**But what is purpose of `DataGrid.items.add(object)`**

in winform it was simply `add(key, val)`. Is WPF all about binding and there isn't any simple way to add data to grid without `datasource`? where did the `key, val` gone with WPF DataGrid

Comment: did you try to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx first? Especially the 'Binding to Data' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the WPF way is much better and simpler than the horrible winforms approach.**

in winforms, when you "put stuff" into the UI,

```
DataGrid.Rows.Add(myobject);
```

it becomes `object` and therefore you need to resort to a bunch of horrible casting techniques:

```
var myobject = DataGrid.Row[x] as MyClass;
```

which is horrible and lends itself to all sorts of runtime-errors that blow in the End User's face.

Not to mention you need to actually do the same stuff twice, one to "put" the stuff in the UI, and then again to "get" the stuff from the UI.

with WPF, everything is beautiful and DataBound and strongly typed, because you don't "put stuff" in the UI, instead, you put stuff into a strongly-typed .Net object, such as an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

```
MyCollection.Add(myobject);
```

then:

```
MyCollection[x] //this is already an instance of MyClass and does not need any casting.
```

and you don't do the same thing twice, because DataBinding takes care of synchronizing the UI and the Data objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any item to WPF DataGrid like classes, images, texts, etc. unlike winforms binding and each item can be of different types/classes and that is why it takes `object.` Once they are bound the types and properties of the bound object must be stated in the XAML definition so that datagrid can display certain properties of the bound object.

Comment: ty i am getting to understand now